# Please judge my first PCB (Roast my design)

Tags: pcb-design

Below is my first PCB design: an Arduino Micro, ESP01 (wifi), 4 RGB leds and 2 buttons (power and reset). Everything is functioning well on my bread board, so now I want to make a PCB from it. Using Fritzing, I made the following design:

[image]

Now I'm trying to get all the components in a small case. Because I want to learn all about PCB design, please tell me what you have to say when you see this design. Or what I have to think of? Missing resistors or capacitors? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would put decoupling capacitors on the WS2812b chips, since if I remember correctly they do not include on onboard.

Comment: For a board like this I would use copper pours for your power and ground. This would eliminate the need for the vias. Also, make your traces come out of the center of the pads, not the edges. Furthermore, try to avoid acute angles between tracks and pads or tracks and other tracks. This is more a rollover from older manufacturing methods but is still good practice regardless.

Comment: How are you mounting the board? Maybe add some mounting holes.

Comment: To know if the PCB connections are as planned, we would need to see the plan which this is based from. The schematics. For example, driving LEDs that require 5V signal with a device that outputs only a 3.3V signal might be something that will not reliably work. Especially when when power supply and ground wiring are just as narrow as data wires.

Comment: It can be a single layer board.

Comment: Will the Arduino be installed in a socket? If it is soldered directly, there is a chance the pins on the back side of the button will touch the bottom of the Arduino.

Comment: Also I only see one button and no ESP32. Are you sure this board has all the stuff you want? Or maybe the other stuff is connected to the header so it's not on this board?

Comment: @user253751 It's an ESP-01 not an ESP32. ESP-01 is an ESP8266 module with an 8-pin (2x4) 0.1" header.

Comment: When you put the board together you may find that the ESP-01 won't actually fit next to the Arduino because their headers are so close together. Move them apart a bit.

Comment: @user253751 The ESP01 is on top of the PCB, the Micro on the other side.

Answer (score 2):

My first PCB was quite similar to what you have done. I learnt a lot of things over time. If I had to do this PCB, I'd make it like this:

[image: PCB image]

I'd add header pins for arduino and esp for easy replacement in case they get damaged. Mounting holes on all corners so that you can easily put it on any surface without the risk of pins getting shorted or PCB wobbling around. Placement of a DC jack for power (this might also require a voltage regulator in your circuit. On-off button could be a slide switch. Having date code or version number printed on the PCB helps. Making a conscious effort to make the PCB look good is something I do, maybe you can also give it a try. It might not improve the performance but everybody loves seeing a good design.

The final PCB will look like this after mounting arduino and esp:

[image: mounted pcb]

Antenna hanging out of PCB to avoid RF interference due to metal on PCB. Alternatively, you can remove ground pour from the PCB under the antenna.

I'll just go ahead and steal a lot of info from the comments:

1. Use of decoupling caps for WS2812B LEDs and ESP (user1850479)
2. Use of copper pour on the PCB. The copper pour is typically connected to GND so you need not route a lot of GND lines. Avoid acute angles wherever possible. This is not much on an issue with superior manufacturing capabilities today but still better to do this. (derstrom8)
3. Mounting holes (qrk)
4. You can make it a single layer board to save money during manufacturing but if its just for learning, go ahead and use multiple layers. No worries (jay)

Answer (score 2):

(Swings hand back) Boi! Just kidding, but here are my thoughts:

- Your LED's should have a 0.1uF decoupling cap added to them.
- Is your ESP board able to accept a 5V input? If not, then you need a 3.3V regulator.
- Add a 300 to 500 Ohm resistor on D5. This is recommended by AdaFruit.

Nice job overall! My first PCB didn't work, lol.

Comment: I know the ESP-01 is a 3.33 V device. But the weird thing is, the ESP doesn't work with an 1117 regulator; the builtin led is barely visible. With the 5V inbput from the Micro, it works like a charm.

Comment: @DorenKooten If the ESP-01 has a 1117V Regulator on it, then you should be fine running it at 5V. The 1117V Regulator has a 1V dropout, meaning if you put 3.3V on the input of the regulator, you will get 2.3V on the output.